# Question about How to assign the order of vertices of a pial surface in FreeSurfer

Tags: neuroscience, measurement, neural-network, neuroimaging, neuroanatomy

I'm a CIVET user but I recently started to use FreeSurfer.
As far as I know, for a surface from CIVET, its vertices are ordered by upsampling a polygon. So I could access downsampled surface by extracting the fore part of vertices from .obj file. But I am not sure that FreeSurfer follows the same order as CIVET.
Please help me to get how FreeSurfer orders their vertices of a surface.

Many Thanks

Yanghee